# Edit draft-js element in form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, draftjs

[Argument of type 'ContentState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKSxA.png)

I'm trying to display generated content from draft-js that I saved in stateToHtml when created. And now on the Edit Modal I want to display the draft-js with the existing text, but I'm running into an error from the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it in the following way

```
  useEffect(() => {
if (!loading && data) {
  const contentState = stateFromHTML(data.post.description);
  setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(contentState));
}  }, [loading]);
```

libs `draft-js-import-html`, `draft-js`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).